# Append to existing Xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012, append

I have a Xml File below that I am trying to load in to visual studio then append another entry for D100 to the file then write or append it 1000 times.

The code below saves the document but nothing gets appended.

```
<flp:Tab xmlns:flp="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   Title="Testing">
  <flp:Form Number="0" id="1005" />
  <flp:Rev Time="2013-01-21T15:08:00">
    <flp:Author Name="Brad" Aid="15" />
  </flp:Rev>
  <flp:Designs Id="D100">
    <flp:D100 Number="1">
      <flp:Code>A</flp:Code>
      <flp:Documented>true</flp:Documented>
      <flp:Note>In Process</flp:Note>
      <flp:Testers>
        <flp:Tester Name="David">
          <flp:Titles>
            <flp:Title Number="0" Name="Entry 1">
              <flp:Start>Begin</flp:Start>
              <flp:Finish>End</flp:Finish>
            </flp:Title>
          </flp:Titles>
        </flp:Tester>
      </flp:Testers>
      <flp:TestGivers>
        <flp:TestGiver Name="James" />
      </flp:TestGivers>
      <flp:IsRequired>true</flp:IsRequired>
      <flp:IsOptional>false</flp:IsOptional>
    </flp:D100>
  </flp:Designs>
</flp:Tab>
```

I am trying to append and write out the information 1000 times in the Xml File

Here is my C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml;


namespace AppendXml
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("C:\\Desktop\\Temp.xml");

            //XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Tab");

            XmlElement D100 = doc.CreateElement("D100");
            D100.SetAttribute("Number", "2");

            XmlElement Code = doc.CreateElement("Code");
            Code.InnerText = "B";

            XmlElement Documented = doc.CreateElement("Documented");
            Documented.InnerText = "false";

            XmlElement Note = doc.CreateElement("Note");
            Note.InnerText = "Complete";

            XmlElement Tester = doc.CreateElement("Tester");
            Tester.SetAttribute("Name", "John");

            XmlElement Title = doc.CreateElement("Title");
            Title.SetAttribute("Number", "0");
            Title.SetAttribute("Name", "Ronald");

            XmlElement Start = doc.CreateElement("Start");
            Start.InnerText = "Begin";

            XmlElement Finish = doc.CreateElement("Finish");
            Finish.InnerText = "End";

            XmlElement TestGiver = doc.CreateElement("TestGiver");
            TestGiver.SetAttribute("Name", "Jeremy");

            XmlElement IsRequired = doc.CreateElement("IsRequired");
            IsRequired.InnerText = "true";

            XmlElement IsOptional = doc.CreateElement("IsOptional");
            IsOptional.InnerText = "false";




            D100.AppendChild(IsOptional);
            D100.AppendChild(IsRequired);
            D100.AppendChild(TestGiver);
            D100.AppendChild(Finish);
            D100.AppendChild(Start);
            D100.AppendChild(Title);
            D100.AppendChild(Tester);
            D100.AppendChild(Note);
            D100.AppendChild(Documented);
            D100.AppendChild(Code);

            //root.AppendChild(D100);
            //doc.AppendChild(root);

            doc.Save("test13.xml");



        }
      }
    }
```

The document saves but noting appends.  What am I leaving out?

Comment: have you thought about using `XPATH` to do this instead? also how are you writing this 1000 times when you don't have any of your code in a Loop.. show code that is relevant should that for loop be un commented..?

Comment: I commented out the for loop to try later.  No I have not thought about XPath, I will look into that now. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextWriter()`. It has been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append `D100` to `flp:Designs` - now you are not appending it to anything, hence nothing gets added to the document:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("flp", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
XmlNode designs = doc.SelectSingleNode("//flp:Designs", nsmgr);
designs.AppendChild(D100);
```

You are also creating `D100` in the default namespace, probably you want to create it in the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` namespace with `flp` prefix as the rest of the XML:

```
XmlElement D100 = doc.CreateElement("flp", "D100", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
```

Lastly: `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` is a standard namespace, that here is used for some custom XML, this is in general wrong.